# Execution of old Hang Fire jobs even after deleting the database

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-server-side, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I ran into a strange problem. I used Hang Fire in a software under Blazor Server and .NET Core that I had no problem with, and now I have come across this problem that when I request to create any job, I see a bunch of jobs that I don't know where they come from, but they are related to the software. They are in Queue!

For testing, I completely changed the database and created a new database and also copied the Hangfire tables to be created again, but I was surprised to see that the same job was created and inside the Hangfire dashboard and a dashboard based on the same I created it manually, they can be seen.
Thank you for knowing the solution to this issue. Or at least something I noticed is that the information is not in the database. If they are not in the database, where are they stored?

Comment: Delete those Job's Manually from `Recurring Jobs` that will resolve Your issue.

Comment: They are stored in code somewhere then. Check for the job registration in code https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

May be You are imported table with data so those Job name's already exit's in that table. No need to create table's manually `Hangfire` will automatically create those table's not exist in that data base. Delete them Manually from `Recurring Jobs` Tab.
To Delete them from Code Level follow below line.

```
RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists("Test Job");
```